# Picking rows with specific column matching conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` with 2291 rows and 4 columns, and I want to pick those rows whose column 3 match with column 2 of the next row, and start again from the next matched row and end until the matching goes on until it stops.

I tried using a `for` loop from `1:nrow(df)`, but this is not exactly accurate as `i` (I think) doesn't really start from the point of matched row.

My current code is like this:

```
test <- NULL 
x <- c()
y <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df[i,3]==df[i+1,2]){
        x <- df[i,]
        y <- df[i+1,]
        i = i+1 #stuck at this
    }
    test <- rbind(test,x,y)
}
```

Sample data looks like this:

```
X  2670000  3750000    C
X  3830000  8680000   E3
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X 10120000 11130079    D
X 11170079 11810079   E3
X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
X 12810079 13530079   E3
X 13530079 14050079   E3
X 14050079 15330079    A
X 15330079 16810079 E2-A
X 16810079 17690079 E2-A
```

What I want is:

```
X  3830000  8680000   E3
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X 10120000 11130079    D

X 11170079 11810079   E3
X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
X 12810079 13530079   E3
X 13530079 14050079   E3
X 14050079 15330079    A
X 15330079 16810079 E2-A
X 16810079 17690079 E2-A
```

I'm actually interested in the column 4 values. After such a condition when 
`df[i,3]` is not equal to `df[i+1,2]`, can the code be updated to store the column 4 values in vectors?

For example: The result for this sample would be:

```
vector_1
"E3" "E1-A" "D"

vector_2
"E3" "E2-A" "E3" "E3" "A" "E2-A" "E2-A"
```

What I get so far is:

```
X  3830000  8680000   E3
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X 10120000 11130079    D
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X 10120000 11130079    D
X 11170079 11810079   E3
X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
X 12810079 13530079   E3
```

If I go from row 1 to the last row of my df, I want to keep adding column 4 values in a vector as long as column 3 of `i` matches column 2 of `i+1`. Once that condition breaks, the next time the same condition is met, I want to keep storing the column 4 values again.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to always include the last row? if `i  == nrow(df)` then there is `df[i+1, 3]`...

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use the `lead` function from the dplyr package.

> `lead(x, n = 1L, default = NA, order_by = NULL, ...)` Find the "next" or "previous" values in a vector. Useful for comparing values ahead of or behind the current values.

This also allows you to avoid the for-loop entirely. Since you haven't named your columns in the question, I'll use another example:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(2, 999, 4, 5, 999))

print(df) # In this example, we want to keep the 1st, 3rd, and 4th rows.
     a   b
   1 1   2
   2 2 999
   3 3   4
   4 4   5
   5 5 999

matching_df <- df[df$b == dplyr::lead(df$a, 1, default = FALSE), ]
print(matching_df)
      a b
    1 1 2
    3 3 4
    4 4 5

non_matching_df <- df[df$b != dplyr::lead(df$a, 1, default = FALSE), ]
print(non_matching_df)
      a   b
    2 2 999
    5 5 999
```

Comment: Thanks! What I am also interested in is to get the next row after the column has matched. Can the code be changed to obtain that? So in your example, I should get row 1 and 2 (because 2 matched from 1), then again row 3,4 and 5.

Comment: If I go from row 1 to the last row of my df, I want to keep adding column 4 values in a vector as long as column 3 of `i` matches column 2 of `i+1`. Once that condition breaks, the next time the same condition is met, I want to keep storing the column 4 values again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way :

```
# indices of the changes
changed <- c(head(df[[3]],-1) != df[-1,2])
# split by cumsum of those
split_ <- split(df[-1,],cumsum(changed))

split_ 

# $`1`
# V1       V2       V3   V4
# 2  X  3830000  8680000   E3
# 3  X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
# 4  X 10120000 11130079    D
# 
# $`2`
# V1       V2       V3   V4
# 5   X 11170079 11810079   E3
# 6   X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
# 7   X 12810079 13530079   E3
# 8   X 13530079 14050079   E3
# 9   X 14050079 15330079    A
# 10  X 15330079 16810079 E2-A
# 11  X 16810079 17690079 E2-A

# Then to get your vectors :

lapply(split_,`[[`,4)

# $`1`
# [1] "E3"   "E1-A" "D"   
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "E3"   "E2-A" "E3"   "E3"   "A"    "E2-A" "E2-A"
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
X  2670000  3750000    C   
X  3830000  8680000   E3
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X 10120000 11130079    D        
X 11170079 11810079   E3
X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
X 12810079 13530079   E3
X 13530079 14050079   E3
X 14050079 15330079    A           
X 15330079 16810079 E2-A                     
X 16810079 17690079 E2-A
",stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: That's simply beautiful

Answer (score 2):

Instead of for loop use repeat. It's much easier this way. First create a duplicate column of 2nd column from 2nd row onwards and compare. I used your sample  data and got desired results -

```
data = read.csv('clipboard', sep = "", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

data$v22 = c(data$V2[2:nrow(data)],0)  
data
    V1       V2       V3   V4      v22
 1   X  2670000  3750000    C  3830000
 2   X  3830000  8680000   E3  8680000
 3   X  8680000 10120000 E1-A 10120000
 4   X 10120000 11130079    D 11170079
 5   X 11170079 11810079   E3 11810079
 6   X 11810079 12810079 E2-A 12810079
 7   X 12810079 13530079   E3 13530079
 8   X 13530079 14050079   E3 14050079
 9   X 14050079 15330079    A 15330079
 10  X 15330079 16810079 E2-A 16810079
 11  X 16810079 17690079 E2-A        0
```

find first match

```
 i = 0
 repeat {
   i = i+1
   if (data$V3[i] == data$v22[i]){
     cat(paste('First Match at row',i))
     break
   }    
 }
```

Now save additional match rows and keep looking after match breaks and save additional match values

```
 df = data.frame(NULL)
 xstart = c(i)
 xend = NULL
 repeat{
   if (data$V3[i] == data$v22[i]){
     df = rbind(df,data[i,])
     i = i+1
   } else { xend = c(xend,i)
     if (i < nrow(data)){
     repeat {
       i = i +1
       if (data$V3[i] == data$v22[i]){
       cat(paste('Next Match at row',i))
       xstart = c(xstart,i)
       break
          }
        }
      }
     }     

   if (i == nrow(data)){
     break
        }
  }
```

print result

```
if (length(xend) < length(xstart)) {xend = c(xend,nrow(data))}

for (l in 1:length(xend)){
  print(data$V4[xstart[l]:xend[l]])
}

 [1] "E3"   "E1-A" "D"   
 [1] "E3"   "E2-A" "E3"   "E3"   "A"    "E2-A" "E2-A"
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: I realized that I was missing some conditions I updated the code**

If you just want to keep the result of the 4th column you can try this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
X  2670000  3750000    C   
X  3830000  8680000   E3
X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
X 10120000 11130079    D        
X 11170079 11810079   E3
X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
X 12810079 13530079   E3
X 13530079 14050079   E3
X 14050079 15330079    A           
X 15330079 16810079 E2-A                     
X 16810079 17690079 E2-A
",stringsAsFactors=F)

eq=c(-1,df$V3[1:(nrow(df)-1)]-df$V2[2:nrow(df)])

storeV3 <- list()
vector_id = 0

for(i in 1:length(eq)){
    if(eq[i] ==  0)
        storeV3[[paste0("vector_",vector_id)]]=c(storeV3[[paste0("vector_",vector_id)]],df$V4[i])
    if(eq[i] !=  0){
        if(i> 1 && eq[i-1] ==  0){
            vector_id = vector_id + 1
            storeV3[[paste0("vector_",vector_id)]]=c(storeV3[[paste0("vector_",vector_id)]],df$V4[i])
        }
        else if(i < length(eq)  && eq[i+1] ==  0)
            storeV3[[paste0("vector_",vector_id)]]=c(storeV3[[paste0("vector_",vector_id)]],df$V4[i])
    }
}
```

The trick I use is to first create a vector to know the indices of the matches and then store the value of `V3` in lists of vectors which indices are updated on the fly. This gives me:

```
> storeV3
$vector_0
[1] "E3"   "E1-A" "D"

$vector_1
[1] "E3"   "E2-A" "E3"   "E3"   "A"    "E2-A" "E2-A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that does the tasks.

## Results

```
# Results
generate(df)
# [[1]]
#   X1       X2       X3   X4
# 2  X  3830000  8680000   E3
# 3  X  8680000 10120000 E1-A
# 4  X 10120000 11130079    D
# 
# [[2]]
#    X1       X2       X3   X4
# 5   X 11170079 11810079   E3
# 6   X 11810079 12810079 E2-A
# 7   X 12810079 13530079   E3
# 8   X 13530079 14050079   E3
# 9   X 14050079 15330079    A
# 10  X 15330079 16810079 E2-A
# 11  X 16810079 17690079 E2-A
```

To only have the vectors in question, you can either modify the function `generate` or simply

```
out <- generate(df)    
vec <- lapply(seq_along(out), function (k) out[[k]]$X4)    
vec
# [[1]]
# [1] "E3"   "E1-A" "D"   
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "E3"   "E2-A" "E3"   "E3"   "A"    "E2-A" "E2-A"
```

## Functions

```
finder <- function (k, dt) {
  dt <- dt[k:nrow(dt),]
  index <- NA_integer_
  col2 <- as.integer(.subset2(dt,2L))
  col3_first <- as.integer(.subset2(dt,3L))[1]
  index <- which(col2 == col3_first)[1L] +k-1
  index
}
getIndex <- function (k, dt) {
  curr <- finder(k, dt)
  if (curr == nrow(dt) || is.na(curr)) return (curr)
  out <- c(k, curr)
  s <- k
  while (!is.na(curr)) {
    s <- s+1
    curr <- finder(s, dt)
    out <- c(out, curr)
  }
  out <- out[!is.na(out)]
  out
}
generate <- function (dt) {
  rows <- 1:nrow(dt)
  skip <- integer(0)
  counter <- 0L
  res <- list()
  for (k in rows) {
    if (k %in% skip) next
    index <- getIndex(k, dt)
    if (is.na(index) || length(index) == 1) next
    skip <- c(skip, index)
    counter <- counter + 1L
    res[[counter]] <- df[index,]
  }
  res
}
```

## Explanation

For a given row number `k`

- `finder` will yield the first `n` (> `k`) such that `df[k,3] == df[i,2]`
- `getIndex` will yield the longest increasing sequence `(k=)k_0;k_1;...;k_n` such that 

  `df[k_i,3] == df[k_i+1,2]` for all `i = 1;...;n`

Finally, `generate` yields the sequence from `getIndex` for all rows, however if a given row `k` is contained in a previous sequence, then it skips that row.

**Data**

```
structure(list(X1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X"), X2 = c("2670000", "3830000", "8680000", "10120000", 
"11170079", "11810079", "12810079", "13530079", "14050079", "15330079", 
"16810079"), X3 = c("3750000", "8680000", "10120000", "11130079", 
"11810079", "12810079", "13530079", "14050079", "15330079", "16810079", 
"17690079"), X4 = c("C", "E3", "E1-A", "D", "E3", "E2-A", "E3", 
"E3", "A", "E2-A", "E2-A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score -3):

I made a scrappy code like this, seems to work:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df[i,3]==df[i+1,2]){
        next
        x <- df[i,]
        y <- df[i+1,]
        i = i+1
    }
    test <- rbind(test,x,y)
}

test <- test[!duplicated(test),]

v <- list()
j <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
    if(test[i,3]!=test[i+1,2]){
        v[[i]] <- test[(j+1):i,4]
        j <- i
        next
    }
}

v <- v[!is.na(v)]
```